How to make event handler delegate know which event is calling it
My code boiled down to the actual problem: (out of a larger project for unittests)
// define all needed delegates for all events in myInstance
EventHandler oea = (o, ea) => GenericEventHandler(o, ea);
EventHandler<int> oi = (o, i) => GenericEventHandler(o, i);
// more 

myInstance.GetType().GetEvents().Foreach(ei => {
  // here I check the delegate of EventInfo to se which handler to use
  ....
  AssignEvent(myItem, ei, oea); // or
  AssignEvent(myItem, ei, oi);  // or even more
  ....
});
...
private static void AssignEvent(object instance, EventInfo @event, Delegate handler)
{
    var iName = instance.GetType().Name;
    WriteTrace($"Assign {@event.EventHandlerType.Name} to {iName}.{@event.Name}");
    @event.AddEventHandler(instance, handler);
}
private static void GenericEventHandler(params object[] o)
{
    WriteTrace("$Event from {....} invoked");
}
```

I would like to know the eventname calling the handler at runtime. The @event.Name is right there, but how do I let the handler know about it.
Since the eventhandler is hooked up this way, the StackTrace from within the GenericEventHandler does not contain any clues to the name of the event.
I have looked at DynamicMethod, Reflection, Expressions and much more, but could not find a way to do it.
I would like to stay away from Emit and IL.

Idea: GenericEventHandler could - instead of being static - be an instance method of a class containing the event name as property.

Thanks, just viewing the example, could lead one to take that approach. I left out that I'm dealing with a range of different instances each with many events. I use this for unittesting a lot of classes and their event invocations.

maybe something like this  (but only for event EventHandler or EventHandler<T>)

What exactly is it that you want to unit test with this? What subject do you provide what input to what action and what do you want to assert where and on what?

If you change the signature of GenericEventHandler to first accept ÈventInfo instance you can do this:
void Main() {
    var item = new A();
    var eventInfo = item.GetType().GetEvents().FirstOrDefault();
    // just to have the definition before your loop
    Func<EventInfo, EventHandler<int>> eventHandlerGenerator = (eventInfo)
        => new EventHandler<int>((o, ea) => GenericEventHandler(eventInfo, o, ea));
    
    // inside your loop
    EventHandler<int> oi = eventHandlerGenerator(eventInfo);
    AssignEvent(item, eventInfo, oi);
    item.InvokeEvent();
    
}

private static void GenericEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo, params object[] o) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Event from {eventInfo.Name} invoked");
}


private static void AssignEvent(object instance, EventInfo @event, Delegate handler) {
    var iName = instance.GetType().Name;
    @event.AddEventHandler(instance, handler);
}

class A {
    public event EventHandler<int> SomeEvent;

    public void InvokeEvent() {
        SomeEvent.Invoke(this, 42);
    }
}


You can do this with Expressions
void Main()
{
    var item = new Item();
    foreach(var eventInfo in item.GetType().GetEvents())
    {
        AssignEvent(item, eventInfo, GenericEventHandler);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("==================");
    item.RaiseClick(1);
    item.RaiseClick(2);
    item.RaiseClick2(1);
    item.RaiseClick2(2);
    item.RaiseDoubleClick("db click1");
    item.RaiseDoubleClick("db click2");
    item.RaiseOther(null);
    item.RaiseOther(new EventArgs());
    item.RaiseCustom(1, DateTime.Now, "test", null);
}

static Delegate CreateDelegate(EventInfo eventInfo, CommonEventHandler handler)
{
    var eventType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
    var eventHandlerParameters = eventType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters();
    var parametersList = new List<ParameterExpression>();
    foreach (var parameterInfo in eventHandlerParameters)
    {
        parametersList.Add(Expression.Parameter(parameterInfo.ParameterType));
    }
    var array = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), parametersList.Select(pe => pe.Type.IsValueType ? Expression.Convert(pe, typeof(object)) : (Expression)pe));
    var handlerCall = Expression.Call(handler.Target == null ? null : Expression.Constant(handler.Target), handler.Method, Expression.Constant(eventInfo), array);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(eventType, handlerCall, false, parametersList);
    lambda.ToString().Dump();
    return lambda.Compile();
}


static void AssignEvent(object instance, EventInfo eventInfo, CommonEventHandler handler)
{
    var iName = instance.GetType().Name;
    Console.WriteLine($"Assign {eventInfo.EventHandlerType.Name} to {iName}.{eventInfo.Name}");
    eventInfo.AddEventHandler(instance, CreateDelegate(eventInfo, handler));
}

delegate void CommonEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo, params object[] o);

static void GenericEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo, params object[] o)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Event `{eventInfo.Name}` from '{o[0]}' invoked with parameters: {{{string.Join(", ", o.Skip(1).Select(v=>v is null ? "(null)" : v))}}}");
}

class Item
{
    public event EventHandler<int> Click;
    public event EventHandler<int> Click2;
    public event EventHandler<string> DoubleClick;
    public event EventHandler Other;
    public event CustomDelegate Custom;
    
    public delegate void CustomDelegate(Item sender, int a, DateTime b, string c, object d);
    
    internal void RaiseClick(int i)
    {
        Click?.Invoke(this, i);
    }

    internal void RaiseClick2(int i)
    {
        Click2?.Invoke(this, i);
    }

    internal void RaiseDoubleClick(string s)
    {
        DoubleClick?.Invoke(this, s);
    }

    internal void RaiseOther(EventArgs args)
    {
        Other?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    internal void RaiseCustom(int a, DateTime b, string c, object d)
    {
        Custom?.Invoke(this, a, b, c, d);
    }
}

You can see results here

good answer to the question "How do I use expressions to generate event handler delegates for events via reflection?"

... which seems like what OP wants
